# CSS: expand items in grid on click to its actual content size

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component

I am pretty new to web design and now I am struggling with some designing issues.

I try to do following thing:

- two dimensional array of items that have fixed size
- the items have hidden content, so they expand by click
- clicked item expands until the content is shown (but no more than 100% width or 100% height)
- when clicked item expands, it should fill the width of 1 row. If there are items on the left side, the clicked item should switch to next row and fill it. Items to the right side should be pushed into the next row.

First the part which works:
This is the table:

```
<div class="table-view">
    <my-item class="item"></my-item>
    <my-item id="one" class="item"></my-item>
<my-item class="item"></my-item>
<my-item class="item"></my-item>
</div>
```

table styling:

```
.table-view {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
    gap: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.item {
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
#one {
        background-color: red;
    flex-basis: 0;
}
```

JS part

```
class ItemTable extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.attachShadow({mode: "open"})
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(tableTpl.content.cloneNode(true))

        this.item = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('one');
        this.item.addEventListener('click', () => {
                this.shadowRoot.getElementById('one').style['flex-basis'] = '100%'
            this.item.setFocus(true)
        })
    }
}

window.customElements.define('item-table', ItemTable)
```

Now the difficult part - the item itself:

```
<div class="item-wrapper">
    <div id="close-btn">
        <div class="extendable">here is close button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-small">
        <div id="avatar">here is an avatar</div>
    </div>
    <div id="item-name">display name</div> 
    
    <div class="extendable hidden-content">hidden content</div>
</div>
```

styling

```
.item-wrapper {
    min-width: 16rem;
    min-height: 18rem;
    
    //keep the items small until clicked
    max-width: 16rem;
    max-height: 18rem;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.item-small{
    width: 16rem;
    height: 16rem;
}
#item-name{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0.3rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.extendable {
    display: none;
}
#avatar {
    height: 16rem;
    width: 16rem;
}
#close-btn {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
#close-btn {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
/*mock hidden content for testing purposes*/
.hidden-content{
    width: 18rem;
    height: 46rem;
    border: thick groove black;
}
```

```
class MyItem extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.attachShadow({mode: "open"})
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(itemTpl.content.cloneNode(true))


        this.item = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.item-wrapper');
        this.extendables = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.extendable')
        this.itemName = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#item-name')
    }

    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['is-focused']
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
        if (attrName === 'is-focused') {
            if (newVal === 'true') {
                this.showContent()
            } else {
                this.hideContent()
            }
        }
    }

    setFocus(focus) {
        this.setAttribute('is-focused', focus)
    }

    showContent() {
            this.itemName.style['display']='none'
        this.extendNpcSheet()
    }

    hideContent() {
        this.itemName.style['display'] = 'none'
    }

    extendNpcSheet(){
        this.extendables.forEach(e => {
            e.style['display'] = 'block'
        })
    }
}

window.customElements.define('my-item', MyItem)
```

Here is an link to example how it look like at now:

https://jsfiddle.net/zap08tb7/

as you can see, the "hidden-content" does not expand in height. And the element does not expand to its content size, but to 100% of the width. I have no idea how I could achieve that. I am happy about any hint that you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

I find this question to be pretty confusing, but I think that this is what the OP is asking for.  OP, if not, please provide some more details in your question - cleaning up your fiddle to more clearly demonstrate the problem/intended workflow might be a pretty good place to start, as right now, I don't really understand what it is illustrating.

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");


function toggle(e) {
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('expanded');
}


for (var item of items)
{
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => toggle(e));
}
```

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item{
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  transition: max-width 2s;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.expanded{
   max-width: 100%;
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color: red;
}

.content{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item" id="2">
    <div class="content">
    Some short-ish content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="3">
    <div class="content">
      a;dfj;laksjdf;lkajsdf;ljas;dflkjasl;dfjl;aksfd;lasdfl;kjasl;kdfj
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="content">
    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
     <div class="content">
    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="content">
    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="last">
    <div class="content">
      afd;jasl;dfj la;sjdf ;laj dsf;la jsfdl;k jasdfl;kj al;kdf j;la fd
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

OP, if you have specific questions about my implementation, feel free to ask, but since your problem is pretty vague I don't want to put a bunch of time into explaining it until I know it's actually answering the question.

Comment: Regardless of whether this answers your question or not, I also want to link you to [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you out with future questions, as including implementation details like templates and shadow dom in your Fiddle are probably unnecessary and distract from the actual question being asked.